# converting a time interval to a duration in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object

I'm working in javascript - and I have a key-value object, that holds in his "value" field this: 9.00 _ 12.30.
This represents a start and end time for a certain session, and I would like to convert it to a duration (meaning 9.00 _ 12.30 --> 3:30 or 3.5).
How can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use split function:

```
t = '9.00_12.30'.split('_');
t0 = t[0].split('.');
t1 = t[1].split('.');
```

And get interval:

```
interval = t1[0]-t0[0]+t1[1]/60-t0[1]/60;
```

Comment: Works great - Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var t = '9.00 _ 12.30'.split(/\W/).map(parseFloat), h, m, r;

t = (t[3] * 60 + t[4]) - (t[0] * 60 + t[1]); // convert `time` values to minutes
m = t % 60;                                  // get minutes
h = (t  - m) / 60;                           // get hours
r = h + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m);        // the resulting string

alert(r);
```